# Mock java.lang.Runtime with PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

want to write an unittest for a method like

```
public static void startProgram() {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, file);
}
```

I don't want to inject the runtime object for some reasons, so I wanted to stub the getRuntime method that it returns a Runtime mock... I tried it this way:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Runtime.class)
public class ProgramTest {

    @Test
    public void testStartProgram() {
        Runtime mockedRuntime = PowerMockito.mock(Runtime.class);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Runtime.class);
        Mockito.when(Runtime.getRuntime()).thenReturn(mockedRuntime);

        ... //test
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Actually nothing seems to be mocked. In the test the normal Runtime object is used.

Anyone any idea why this doesn't work and/or how it works?

As this mini example seems not to reproduce the problem here is the full test code:
method to test (shortened)

```
public static synchronized long startProgram(String workspace) {
    // Here happens someting with Settings which is mocked properly
    File file = new File(workspace);
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return 0L;
}
```

and the test:

```
@Test
public void testStartProgram() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Settings.class);
    Mockito.when(Settings.get("timeout")).thenReturn("42");

    Runtime mockedRuntime = Mockito.mock(Runtime.class);
    // Runtime mockedRuntime = PowerMockito.mock(Runtime.class); - no difference
    Process mockedProcess = Mockito.mock(Process.class);

    Mockito.when(mockedRuntime.exec(Mockito.any(String[].class), Mockito.any(String[].class),
                    Mockito.any(File.class))).thenReturn(mockedProcess);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Runtime.class);
    Mockito.when(Runtime.getRuntime()).thenReturn(mockedRuntime);

    startProgram("doesnt matter");
}
```

Then, in the test, the call to Runtime.getRuntime() doesn't bring the mock and that's why an IOException is thrown because the String is no directory...

Comment: Your example works just fine for me with `Mockito 1.9.5` & `Powermock 1.5`. What versions are you using?

Comment: Mockito 1.9.5 & PowerMock 1.5.4

Comment: Same thing. Can you please post the complete code for your class and test?

Comment: I added a shortened version of the method which I want to test and the nearly complete version of the test method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad in the comments, apologies, I had an inner class for the test and that's why I had no trouble. I then realized this and saw your `@PrepareForTest(Runtime.class)` which should read `@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)` (replace MyClass with whatever name you have) because `Runtime` is a *system class*. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockSystem) and find more examples [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/blob/master/modules/module-test/mockito/junit4/src/test/java/samples/powermockito/junit4/system/SystemClassUserTest.java).

Comment: But what I have to prepare with this annotation are classes, that I want to mock wit PowerMock (and can't be mocked with Mockito). And here I want to mock the static method getRuntime from Runtime class, so I have to prepare the Runtime class. Or am I wrong???

Comment: Normally yes, except for *system classes* when you have to prepare the calling class. I've corrected the URL from the reply to point to the documentation regarding this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You must write a wrapper class for `Runtime`, because it's system class.

```
public class AppShell {
  public Process exec(String command) {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  }
}
```

Then in unit test, use `@PrepareForTest(AppShell.class)` instead of `@PrepareForTest(Runtime.class)`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(AppShell.class)
public class AppShellTest {

    @Mock private Runtime mockRuntime;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Runtime.class);

        when(Runtime.getRuntime()).thenReturn(mockRuntime);
        when(mockRuntime.exec()).thenReturn("whatever you want");

        // do the rest of your test
    }
}
```

---

See [PowerMock - Mocking system classes](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System)