# @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) says @RunWith not applicable to method

Tags: java, powermock

I have a gradle file

```
testCompile('junit:junit')
testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.5')
testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.5')
testCompile('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.5')
```

And my test file

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExperimentService.class)
```

There seems to be an error with the @RunWith and I have can't seem to find the problem, it just says that '@RunWith' not applicable to method.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you see the RunWith.class, target for this annotation is ElementType.Type which means it can only be applied to Class, enum or interface declaration.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Inherited
public @interface RunWith {
    Class<? extends Runner> value();
}
```

You cannot apply this annotation over a method.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean because I'm actually following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039184/mock-java-lang-runtime-with-powermockito and this gist.github.com/dimhold/5759950 examples as I'm trying to mock an execute command <Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());> Are you saying that I can't do it this way? Sorry very new to this.

Answer (score 2):

Oh never mind I found my mistake, it seems that I put the statement within the class.